# Lombok is not supported in New Android Studio Update BumbelBee

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

[enter image description here][1]

It shows the following  error when you add the Lombok plugin from diskspace which was downloaded from their website
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4boP3.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The workaround was found [this link](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1107#issuecomment-1024174446)
As the New Update of `Android Studio(AS)` to `BumbleBee` the Google **Forgot to include the plugin** `Lombok` in `Android Studio`.
So I am writing this for the help of anyone who updated their `Android Studio` and now their `lombok` plugin is not working or anyone who wants to use lombok `enter code here`plugin in their `Android Studio`

The Steps are following
Steps:

1: [Download/Install `IntelliJ IDEA Community`](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html)

2: Open the directory(folder) in which the `Intellij IDEA Community` is installed

3: Go into the directory(folder) name which is **"plugins"**

4: Copy the directory(folder) named `lombok`

5: Go into the directory(folder) where `Android Studio` is installed

6: Go into the **Plugin directory**(folder) of `android studio`

7: **Paste** the folder which was copied at step 4

8: **Restart** `Android Studio`

Comment: Be aware that in some cases such "installed" Lombok plugin can disable code suggestions in Android Studio

Comment: Do you know why this issues occurs? I have the same problem you mentioned Antares.